# How to modify data held by the cursor only, without the database updating?

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor, updating

I have a cursor as below:

```
CURSOR employee_cur IS
       SELECT * FROM employee where department_id='accounts';
```

I need to modify the data for some specific rows inside the cursor only. Later on whoever will use this cursor, they should find the modified data only, from this cursor.

I don't want to update any DB table. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

A cursor is a read-only structure.  It is a pointer to a SQL statement.  When that SQL statement is executed, the data will be fetched from the database.  You can manipulate the data in the `SELECT` statement itself as much as you would like.  But you can't modify the data that the cursor will return once the cursor is opened.

You can, of course, manipulate the data in the `SELECT` statement.  For example, your query can do something like

```
SELECT employee_id, 
       first_name,
       last_name,
       (CASE WHEN last_name = 'King' 
             THEN salary*2
             ELSE salary
         END) salary
  FROM employee
```

to double any employee named "King"'s salary in the result set.  You can use a `UNION ALL` to return rows that don't exist in the database, i.e.

```
SELECT employee_id, 
       first_name,
       last_name,
       salary
  FROM employee
UNION ALL
SELECT -1,
       'Justin',
       'Cave',
       17
  FROM dual
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get you're trying to achieve is to return either varray or nested table (pipelined or by out param). When you're populate it you could to do all changes you need. If you really need to return a cursor and do not need something like UPDATE CURRENT OF you could put data in varray/nested table, past as the IN param into pipilined function and create  cursor as select * from your pipilened function(prepared vararray/nested table).

You could do all treatment inside your function, put results at any temporary table and return the cursor from the temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a collection-

```
type my_emp_table_type is table of employee%rowtype;
myEmpTable  my_emp_table_type;
```

And then use `BULK COLLECT` to collect the cursor data, by

```
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO myEmpTable 
  FROM employee 
 WHERE department_id='accounts';
```

Modify collection elements like-

```
myEmpTable(10).id := 10;
myEmpTable(10).first_name  := 'John';
myEmpTable(10).last_name   := 'Doe';
```

And use `myEmpTable` wherever you want.
**Note**, you can loop through the collection as

```
 for i in myEmpTable.first .. myEmpTable.last loop
    if myEmpTable.(i)last_name = 'Doe'
    then
          myEmpTable.(i)sal := 50000;
    end if;
    ...
    ....
 end loop;
```